# Cancel animation when click or remove class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove or cancel an animation, when I click on a div it opens a second div with a sub menu that is fine, the thing is that I have added a sub menu and it shows when hover but if I click on any link on the hover link it opens the second div...

```
<div class="togger">
   Nice Title
     <div class="sub-menu-hover">
       <a href="foo.html">Some page</a>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="hiden-menu">
   <a href="foo.html">Some page</a>
</div>
```

So when I click on "Nice Title" it display the ".hiden-menu", that is fine, when I hover on "Nice Title" it display the ".sub-menu-hover" also is fine, the problem is when I click on any menu "a" tag inside the ".sub-menu-hover".
What it does is that it opens the ".hiden-menu" and I don't want that...
I notice that when I click to whatever is inside ".toggler" it add a class ".active" and it opens the ".hiden-menu", so how can I prevent that when someone click inside ".sub-menu-hover"? it should only take you to whatever link you click on...
I did this

```
<script>
   (function($) {
        $(".sub-menu-hover").click(function(){
            $('.toggler').removeClass('active');
        })
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

but didn't do anything...

Comment: please post the css you are using

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".togger p").click(function() {
  $(".hiden-menu").toggle();
  $(".sub-menu-hover").hide();
});
$(".togger p").mouseover(function() {
  $(".sub-menu-hover").show();
});
$(".togger p").mouseout(function() {
  $(".sub-menu-hover").hide();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu-hover,
.hiden-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="togger">
  <p>Nice Title</p>
  <div class="sub-menu-hover">
    <a href="#">hover Some page</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hiden-menu">
  <a href="#">click Some page</a>
</div>
```